# Sql Oracle query - field contains special characters or alpha

Tags: sql, oracle, select

need to see if a taxid field contains letters or any special characters:. *,!,?,@,#,$,&,+,(,),/

How can I write this SQL?

Comment: Define "or". Do you mean, show all the taxid fields that contain at least one letter or at least one special character? That's pretty odd; rather, I suspect that you could formulate your problem more carefully.

Comment: Hi, am trying to validate the taxid field contains only numbers and nothing else.  Pulling data in from various sources where there is no validation check against what is entered for a taxid, so am checking data quality.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has regexp_like:

```
select * from tablename where regexp_like(columnname, '[*!?@#$&+()/]');
```

Comment: The above has all the special characters, do I just add the alphabet to it to cover all the letters?  Thanks!

Comment: @CherylLHubert - there are much more compact ways to check for the existence or non-existence of letters, digits, punctuation characters etc. than to enumerate them all, even if you use `regexp_like`. However, in this problem you do not need to use regular expressions at all. Whenever possible, you should choose solutions that use standard string functions (that is, non-regular-expression functions), since regular expressions are much slower - the price we pay for their much greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to display all the taxid's that are NOT entirely composed of digits:

```
select taxid
from   your_table
where  translate(taxid, '.0123456789', '.') is not null
```

`TRANSLATE` will "translate" (replace) each period in the input with a period in the output. Since the other characters in the second argument do not have a corresponding character in the third argument, they will simply be deleted. If the result of this operation is **not** `null`, then the `taxid` contains at least one character that is not a digit. If `taxid` is all digits, the result of the operation is `null`. Note that the period character used here is needed, due to an oddity in Oracle's definition of `TRANSLATE`: if any of its arguments is `null`, then so is its return value. That doesn't make a lot of sense, but we must work with the functions as Oracle defined them.